# I forgot to sign in to Data Explorer. Can I get my queries back?

Tags: support, data-explorer, user-accounts

I recently created a series of queries in the data explorer which I'm quite proud of. To wit, they are [What reputation do people with Popular/Notable/Famous Question badges typically have?](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/152440), and after it branches to [this](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/152447), [this](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/152446) and [this](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/152452) queries, in support of [this meta.physics.se question](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5283).

Unfortunately, I forgot to sign in before starting the write-up, so those queries are now attributed to Anonymous. I would quite like to have them associated with my account instead. The IP address record should show that it was me doing it, as I logged in on the same computer just before forking to the final query. Is it possible to, e.g., merge my account with that Anonymous one?

Comment: "Kind of", is probably the best answer to your actual question, but can't you just fork the existing queries while logged in to achieve (almost) the same effect?